# PowerApps Canvas Form - Date Picker error *IF* Selected date is not a Sunday

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

Good morning,

I have a Power Apps Canvas form (connected to a SharePoint list) where I have a date picker field with a weird requirement.

I need the Datacard's error message to read "Must be a Sunday" IF the Selected Date is NOT a Sunday.  How could I make this happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the day of selected date using `Weekday` function like:

```
Weekday(DateControlName.SelectedDate)
```

So, try setting `Text` property of error message label control to:

```
If(Weekday(DateControlName.SelectedDate)=1,"","Must be a Sunday")
```

OR

```
If(Weekday(DateControlName.SelectedDate,StartOfWeek.Sunday)=1,"","Must be a Sunday")
```

Where `DateControlName` is the name of your date picked control and `1` is to check for "Sunday".

Comment: Thanks Ganesh.  The second formula is exactly what I needed.